# MySQL - Grab TIME only if it is not 0 (00:00:00)

Tags: mysql

This is the SELECT I'm using (that's not working)

```
SELECT 
    IF( 
         TIME( `date_time` ) = '00:00:00', 
         DATE( `date_time` ), 
         `date_time`
    ) AS date_time
FROM `table`
```

My Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `graphs` (
  `graph_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `stat_book_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `object_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `object_type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `created_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '1',
  `sparkline` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `sparkline_updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_updated` timestamp NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00' on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`graph_id`),
  KEY `stat_book_id` (`stat_book_id`,`object_id`,`object_type`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Version data

```
Server version: 5.0.91-community
time format: %H:%i:%s
```

This query:

```
SELECT 
    `date_time`, DATE(`date_time`), TIME(`date_time`) 
FROM `graph_values` 
LIMIT 10
```

Returns:

```
date_time   DATE(`date_time`)   TIME(`date_time`)
2010-09-24 00:00:00     2010-09-24  00:00:00
2010-09-19 00:00:00     2010-09-19  00:00:00
2010-09-16 21:05:00     2010-09-16  21:05:00
2010-10-30 00:00:00     2010-10-30  00:00:00
2010-10-08 00:00:00     2010-10-08  00:00:00
2010-09-17 23:50:00     2010-09-17  23:50:00
2010-09-15 00:00:00     2010-09-15  00:00:00
2010-10-23 00:00:00     2010-10-23  00:00:00
2010-09-17 19:24:00     2010-09-17  19:24:00
2010-09-19 19:24:00     2010-09-19  19:24:00
```

This query, however, returns incorrect results:

```
SELECT 
    `date_time`, DATE(`date_time`), TIME(`date_time`), IF( 
        TIME( `date_time` ) = '00:00:00', 
        DATE( `date_time` ), 
        `date_time`
    )
FROM `graph_values`
LIMIT 10
```

Results:

```
date_time   DATE(`date_time`)   TIME(`date_time`)   IF( TIME( `date_time` ) = '00:00:00', DATE( `date_time` ), `date_time` )
2010-09-24 00:00:00     2010-09-24  00:00:00    2010-09-24 00:00:00
2010-09-19 00:00:00     2010-09-19  00:00:00    2010-09-19 00:00:00
2010-09-16 21:05:00     2010-09-16  21:05:00    2010-09-16 21:05:00
2010-10-30 00:00:00     2010-10-30  00:00:00    2010-10-30 00:00:00
2010-10-08 00:00:00     2010-10-08  00:00:00    2010-10-08 00:00:00
2010-09-17 23:50:00     2010-09-17  23:50:00    2010-09-17 23:50:00
2010-09-15 00:00:00     2010-09-15  00:00:00    2010-09-15 00:00:00
2010-10-23 00:00:00     2010-10-23  00:00:00    2010-10-23 00:00:00
2010-09-17 19:24:00     2010-09-17  19:24:00    2010-09-17 19:24:00
2010-09-19 19:24:00     2010-09-19  19:24:00    2010-09-19 19:24:00
```

Anyone have an idea why?

---

#### UPDATE: Solution found.

It seems there is a bug or it is supposed to be the above way. It seems the problem is it can't return a `date` format in two different ways (one with time, one without). It seems that the older versions of MySQL could (see the below tests).

The same test was done in a SQL database and it had the same problem. The simple solution is the following (I believe it's comparable execution-time-wise):

```
SELECT 
     IF( 
          TIME( `date_time` ) = '00:00:00', 
          REPLACE( `date_time`, ' 00:00:00', '' ), 
          `date_time`
     ) AS date_time
FROM `table`
```

Comment: If the time is 0, you only want the date. But else you only want the time? Are you sure that else you don't want **date and time**?

Comment: @Kerry - perfectly alright, unless `SELECT IF(..) as date_time, date_time`, the later date_time column override the first column

Comment: @ Konerak -- you are right, but it still isn't working -- I updated the question.

Comment: @ajreal -- that's acting as an alias, not as a name, I can change it and it still has the same funky results.

Comment: @Kerry - Results returned via api will override it. Anywhere, what is the data type?

Comment: @ajreal -- it's a datetime. Notice Konerak's example below, it didn't work for me. I think there is a bug in my MySQL version (Server version: 5.0.91-community)

Comment: @Kerry - How about explicitly casting `cast (DATE( date_time ) as date)` ?

Comment: @ ajreal -- possibly a good suggestion, I think I found the problem though. Updated with the inforamtion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm thinking you're meaning to do this:

```
SELECT 
     IF( 
          TIME( `date_time` ) = '00:00:00', 
          DATE( `date_time` ), 
          `date_time` 
     ) AS date_time
 FROM `table`
```

So that

```
2010-11-17 08:43:00 -> 2010-11-17 08:43:00
2010-11-17 00:00:00 -> 2010-11-17
```

Full-blown example:

```
CREATE TABLE `testdates` ( `date_time` datetime NOT NULL);

insert into testdates values (now());
insert into testdates values ("2010-11-17 00:00:05");
insert into testdates values ("2010-11-16 00:00:00");
insert into testdates values ("2010-11-15");

SELECT 
     IF( 
          TIME( `date_time` ) = '00:00:00', 
          DATE( `date_time` ), 
          `date_time` 
     ) AS date_time
 FROM testdates;

+---------------------+
| date_time           |
+---------------------+
| 2010-11-17 08:52:06 |
| 2010-11-17 00:00:05 |
| 2010-11-16          |
| 2010-11-15          |
+---------------------+
```

My configuration:

```
mysql> show variables like "version";
+---------------+------------+
| Variable_name | Value      |
+---------------+------------+
| version       | 5.0.26-log |
+---------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like "time_format";
+---------------+----------+
| Variable_name | Value    |
+---------------+----------+
| time_format   | %H:%i:%s |
+---------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: You're right, but it's still giving the full date, despite that every record in the table, right now, has 00:00:00 as the hour.

Comment: It's working here. Can you show your SHOW CREATE TABLE statement? What type is the column?

Comment: @ Konerak -- that's really interesting, I used your code exactly (copy and pasted) and it didn't work. What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @Kerry: Tested on `5.0.26-log` and `5.0.51a-24+lenny2-log`. Can you just do a `SELECT date_time, DATE(date_time), TIME(date_time) from table` for me?